# Paid Support Option for YouTube Higher Ed

Tags: video, youtube

I am writing from Berkeley College. I would like to know if YouTube has an option for paid support for videos posted on our YouTube Channel.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I noticed you would want to be a Google Apps for Education, not business account.  Which includes some form of support and is free.  As far as for specifics on support levels, you'd be best off trying the "contact sales" button at the link below.

Sort of.  If you move the account to a [Google Apps for Education](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/education/) paid account, you can get support for all of the google products offered, which includes youtube.